# Hide checkbox from angular mat-select in case of multiple select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular-material select to create a drop-down where I have provided options to select multiple values.

```
 <accordion [showArrows]="true" class="programstyle">
          <accordion-group heading="EVENTS" [isOpened]="true">
            <div class="">
              <mat-form-field class="width100">
                <mat-select class="width100" placeholder="Events" [(ngModel)]="studentInput.programType" (change)="filter()" id="programTypeValueId" name="programTypeValueId">
                    <mat-option disabled>Select Events</mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let program of programs" [value]="program.campusEventId">{{program.eventName}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </accordion-group>
          <accordion-group heading="SKILLS">
            <div class="">
              <mat-form-field class="width100">
                <mat-select multiple class="width100" placeholder="Select Skills" [(ngModel)]="studentInput.skills" (change)="filter()"  id="skillTypeValueId" name="skillTypeValueId">
                  <mat-option disabled>Select Skills</mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill.lookupValueId">{{skill.lookupValue}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </accordion-group>
          <accordion-group heading="INTERESTS">
            <div class="">
              <mat-form-field class="width100">
                <mat-option>Select Interests</mat-option>
                <mat-select multiple class="width100" placeholder="Select Interests"  [(ngModel)]="studentInput.interest" (change)="filter()" id="interestTypeValueId"
                  name="interestTypeValueId">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let interest of interests" [value]="interest.lookupValueId">{{interest.lookupValue}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
```

This the HTML part.
I have used Select Events in order to define option as Select Events. But i am getting this with checkbox enabled. I don't want the first option in the drop-down to have check-box enabled. Is there any way i can have first option with no-checkboxes?

[image]

Comment: Could you mark my answer as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each `mat-option` has a `mat-pseudo-checkbox` to handle checkbox styles (I inspected it from chrome dev tools). Try this (Angular 5, Material 2):

```
::ng-deep .mat-option:first-child .mat-pseudo-checkbox{ display: none; }
```

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated in angular 6 or above perhaps.

Comment: It's deprecated but there's no any practical alternative

Comment: >> It's deprecated but there's no any practical alternative
That is not true! You can use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`...

Answer (score 4):

You can add `hideSingleSelectionIndicator` like this `<mat-select hideSingleSelectionIndicator>` to remove the mat-pseudo-checkbox. Ref: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: That also true for the <mat-autocomplete>

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make an option with "create new item" in mat multi-select wrapper component, so **Quan VO**' comment works, and I extended it to working example:

*.ts

```
@Input() public enableAddOption: boolean;
@Output() public onAddNew = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

*.html

```
<mat-select
  [formControl]="values"
  [multiple]="isMultiple"
>
  <mat-option *ngIf="enableAddOption" class="hide-checkbox" [value]="null" (click)="onAddNew.emit()">
    <b>{{ enableAddOption ? 'Create new' : '' }}</b>
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">
     <span>{{ option.title }}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

*.scss:

```
::ng-deep .hide-checkbox .mat-pseudo-checkbox { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

::ng-deep is deprecated so we can write this class in styles.css

```
  .mat-option:last-child .mat-pseudo-checkbox  { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add un html ID to the mat-option where the checkbox need to be removed and use css to target the mat speudo checkbox and remove it.

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in the ts file is required.

```
<mat-option id="allOption">
 ...
</mat-option>

#allOption > .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any custom css by using a `mat-optgroup` (https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#creating-groups-of-options)

i.e.

```
<mat-form-field class="width100">
  <mat-select multiple class="width100" placeholder="Select Skills" [(ngModel)]="studentInput.skills" (change)="filter()"  id="skillTypeValueId" name="skillTypeValueId">
    <mat-optgroup label="Select Skills">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill.lookupValueId">
        {{skill.lookupValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please provide other details about the version you are using.

You can do that in multiple ways.
Angular material has selection model class which will allow you to manipulate with all those values.
else you can set the checkbox to *ngIf="alreadySelected" something like that and
link that bool to your ts logic.

Comment: In what way is the version relevant to answering the question? It appears you were able to provide one answer to the question without that information...